# Can I use values from .properties files as Android string resources?

Tags: android, ant

I want to put my google map debug and release key to different properties files:

debug.properties

maps.api.key = 11111

release.properties

maps.api.key = 22222

How could I use them as string resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly. You are welcome to create your own Ant tasks that will generate a string resource file out of properties files or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

Here is a solution to use .properties file in your project.

1 Create a file named app.properties in assets folder of your android project

2 edit the file and write with in properties that you want to use for example as

```
test=success
```

And Save file

3 Write this Method with in your Activity Class

```
  private Properties loadPropties() throws IOException {
  String[] fileList = { "app.properties" };
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  for (int i = fileList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     String file = fileList[i];
     try {
        InputStream fileStream = getAssets().open(file);
        prop.load(fileStream);
        fileStream.close();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ignoring missing property file " + file);
     }
  }
  return prop;
  }
```

4 With in OnCreate Method  write some thing like this

```
     Properties prop = new Properties(); 
     try {
        prop = loadPropties();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
     }
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result " + prop.getProperty("test"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

5 add necessary imports

Comment: more good will be if you declare your own Application class and do this loading from there

Comment: and cast getProperty values as per the need to int or string or whatever